# Configure IIS 8 to allow a script to run

Tags: iis

I'm running iis 8 in a production environment. I have a webpage i created for our local intranet site. This page runs some PHP but relies on a batch file to do some stuff as well.

The batch file runs just fine when I right click it > run as admin, however when called from the php script, it fails to run; access denied.

I know that IIS needs to be configured some way to allow this to run, but I don't know much about iis, and I'm hesitant to just toy around with it in our production environment.

There's already an application pool for the intranet site, which has "enable 32-bit applications" set to true under advanced settings. However the process model identity is set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" which may not have enough permission. Security aside, I don't want to change this to a local admin in fear of breaking something.

Can anybody shed some more light on this, or tell me the process for configuring iis to allow a script to run on a site?

Comment: I assume the script does have to run as admin?

Comment: yes, that is correct... when i don't right click to run as admin, it gives "access denied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for some closure to this- I never did find a solution to allow .bat, .ps1, .exe files to run remotely given the gp restrictions in my environment. What I did end up doing to circumvent this issue is building my app in node.js... which allowed for the processing to be moved to the client side... so I could accomplish what I wanted to do without any server side php or anything.